# "You and me against the world" vs "You and I against the world"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, subjects

I have heard the first sentence in a song and there are also other songs that go something like "Me against the world" and "Me against the music". Shouldn't it be "You and I against..." since the phrase "You and I" is the subject? Or is it not?

Comment: ... I've voted to close as a duplicate too, but the whole issue of what is considered acceptable, and in which registers, still seems unclear. Of course, with a sentence fragment like OP's, one can't even say what case one should start arguing for.

Comment: @RoaringFish this isn't necessarily a duplicate of that question, which is about the objective case.  It also touches on the question of predicate nominatives and the fact that nearly all speakers of English use the objective case there ("it's me" or "that's him").  As Henry's answer notes, though, we can't determine which case is indicated from the information given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

"Me against the world" is not a sentence as it has no verb.

"It was me against the world" is, and to me personally would be fine, though perhaps not to some prescriptive grammarians.  "I am against the world" is also fine.

Extending this, I would therefore also be happy with both "It was you and me against the world" and "You and I were against the world".

So shortening each in a song to either "You and me against the world" or "You and I against the world" would raise no complaints from me, especially since there should always be some artistic licence in such cases.